# Why do some image viewers display color differently?

Tags: linux, colors, color-profiles, image-viewer

On my Fedora 23 machine I've noticed that different image viewers show the colors of images differently (i.e. with different intensity).

In this example the left version of the image is a screenshot from the [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/) viewer the right one is how [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) shows it:
[image]
But not only gimp behaves this way: also the gwenview main picture view shows less colors (but not the thumbnails).

What's the reason for this? And how can I get gimp and gwenview show the same colors as kolourpaint or Shotwell do?

**Update:**

I now tried to just deactivate the [color management](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Gnome/GNOME-Color-Manager-52880.shtml) for my monitor and all applications show the colors in the left picture now.

This seems very strange to me. Why do applications have to apply the profile on their own (rather than it's automatically applied to everything which is being displayed)? This way making a screenshot from a picture viewer which applies the color profile will result in altered color values.

Conclusion:

Looks like the color profile is only applied to *some parts* of (Gnome) applications (remember in *g*wenview the main image viewer is being corrected while the thumbnails are not).

My question seems to be now: How can the activated color profile be applied to all (or at least all Gnome) applications? Color management seems quite useless and misleading to me if it's only applied to some parts of some applications. How do I know whether what I'm seeing is being corrected or not?!

Another update:

Looks like this is an X server problem: on Wayland (Fedora 25) images all look like the right picture. The color profile seems to be applied to all monitor output.

Comment: Viewers designed for professionals may emphasize accuracy, while viewers designed for average users may apply automatic image modification to slightly improve the image for the user's benefit. But, this is a very subject question, I think, and not necessarily likely to receive one correct answer.

Comment: That sounds plausible but in this case it's not the reason. I can open a file in gimp (or gwenview), make a screenshot and display this screenshot again in gimp (or gwenview) and the image looses color every time I do this. To me it looks like gwenview and gimp apply some color correction or HDR effect.